# How to find *all* roots of arbitrarily high degree polynomials (in particular, characteristic polynomials)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots

In eigenvalue characteristic equation computations of large matrices, it is often necessary to find all the the roots of this polynomial. I understand that there is no general explicit solution for irrational roots of polynomials of degree higher than 5. We might thus use numerical approximations, such as Newton's method, to find a root for the polynomial equation.

My question is, for very high degree polynomials, eg. characteristic equation of degree 100, how can we make systematic/algorithmic computation to find *all* the 100 roots to this polynomial? Is there a consistent method that will always find all the roots to this eigenvalue characteristic equation?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question about root-finding in general, but it's important to know that for numerical calculation of eigenvalues one should **not** use the characteristic polynomial. There are other methods that are much better.

Comment: About polynomial roots in general, there are some starting pointers [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Roots_of_polynomials).

Comment: Tom Copeland has written an answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/368105/25104
See also square root of 2 in the OEIS: https://oeis.org/A002193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerical methods that will compute all roots of polynomials of high degree. Some are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Real-root_isolation).

But, actually, one of the best methods is to find the eigenvalues of the polynomial’s companion matrix. This is how the “[roots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html)” function in Matlab works, for example. There are many good numerical methods for computing eigenvalues, some of which are listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms). As you will see, some work by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial, but many do not. The QR algorithm is a popular one.

So, in some sense, you’re looking at the problem backwards: you shouldn’t use polynomial root finding to compute eigenvalues (except maybe in linear algebra homework problems), you should use eigenvalue computations to find roots of polynomials.